# Getting a java.io.NotSerializableException when trying to write custom object to outputStream

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

```
try
{
    CompressedMessage cMessage = new CompressedMessage(messageArea.getText(), false);
    cMessage.compressMessage();         
    EncryptedMessage eMessage = new EncryptedMessage(MessageType.USERMESSAGE, "", cMessage);
    outputStream.writeObject(eMessage);
}
catch (IOException e1)
{
    System.out.println(e1);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

I am trying to send a message to a server (local atm), had no problems when sending data before (in strings) just when trying to send the EncryptedMessage object.

```
public class EncryptedMessage
{
    private MessageType type;
    private String receipent;
    private CompressedMessage message;

    public EncryptedMessage(MessageType T, String R, CompressedMessage mes)
    {
        type = T;
        receipent = R;
        message = mes;
    }

    public MessageType getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(MessageType type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getReceipent()
    {
        return receipent;
    }
    public void setReceipent(String receipent)
    {
        this.receipent = receipent;
    }
    public CompressedMessage getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EncryptedMessage and CompressedMessage should implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) .

Comment: Thanks Peter!  Literally five minutes after posting I realised what I needed to do, but thank you for your response